# Unable to write MySQL temp file when running Rails migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

UPDATE: The sysadmin in my company deleted the /tmp directory and created a
symbolic link to a mounted drive (e.g. ln -s /mnt/somewhere /tmp).
MySQL apparently didn't like this symbolic link.
Once a real /tmp directory on the local filesystem was created the problem went away.

---

I'm running a process (rake db:migrate) which causes MySQL to try to create a temp file.
However, the following error is appearing:

```
Mysql::Error: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_196_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13): 
SHOW FIELDS FROM `user_rules`
```

Errcode 13 apparently is a file permission issue.
The user that is running the process has write permissions to the /tmp directory.
I also searched the web, and someone mentioned that the issue could be the file be prefixed with a pound sign (e.g. '#").

I went to the /tmp directory and tried to create the file and noticed that in certain cases I can't create the file.  So I'm wondering if indeed the pound sign is causing the problem.  And if it is, how can use MySQL or Rails to fix the problem:

```
cd /tmp
echo "Hello" > #sql_123
touch #sql_123

echo "Hello" > "#sql_123"
touch "#sql_123"
```

The 2nd and 3rd commands (without quotes) are failing.  The 4th and 5th lines (with quotes) are working.  So maybe the failure is because of the pound sign not being in quotes or escaped with a backslash.  But again, even if that is the cause, I'm not sure how to tell MySQL or Rails how to deal with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: The sysadmin in my company deleted the /tmp directory and created a
symbolic link to a mounted drive (e.g. ln -s /mnt/somewhere /tmp).
MySQL apparently didn't like this symbolic link.
Once a real /tmp directory on the local filesystem was created the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell you need quotes because # introduces a comment, unless escaped by a backslash or quotes. Those #sql_123 files with a prefix of a pound-sign are temporary files owned by mysql, they are normal. You cannot move them however and whenever they are present you cannot move your database using the binary files, you either need to shutdown and move; or do a mysqldump to SQL.

Now for your sysadmin, did he delete /tmp while mysql was running? Mysql opens files in /tmp and then deletes them from the directory leaving the file-handle open. You would see differences in disk space while the server is up or down. MySQL creates all temporary files as hidden files. This ensures that the temporary files are removed if mysqld is terminated. The disadvantage of using hidden files is that you do not see a big temporary file that fills up the file system in which the temporary file directory is located.

So if you would like to keep the symlink (i.e. to a larger disk) then you would better shutdown mysql, create the link, and then start mysql to find it has no problem with symlinks.